# Lenovo ideapad 110-15ISK power on issue

Tags: windows-10, window

So my laptop keyboard is broken and "power on" Button is included in keyboard. I wanna turn my laptop on without power button. Is there any way to turn on my laptop without power button?(also there's no power management option in my Laptop's BIOS setting)
Any way to turn on laptop with external keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

No, not at all likely. My own x230 power button failed. I took it apart to the extent I could, but I had to obtain a replacement keyboard with working power button from an eBay source (Nordic_keyboards). Replacement buttons simply not available.